# Anagram Search Algorithm Comparison in Python [Tutorial Homework]

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, primes

I am making a simple algorithm sort in Python using defaultdict, creating a hash to use as the key and then just going through the dictionary afterwards and printing out anything with more than a single value.

Originally started by creating the hash by creating a sorted string using:

```
def createHashFromFile(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as fileObj:
        for line in fileObj:
            line = line.lower()
            aHash = ("").join(sorted(line.strip()))
            aSorter[aHash].append(line.strip())
```

However, because the sorted() function is O(n^2) have had the suggestion made to create the hash through prime factorization. I created a dictionary that has mapped all the lower case letters to a prime and then done:

```
def keyHash(word):
    mulValue = 1
    for letter in word:
        letter = letter.lower()
        mulValue = mulValue * primeDict[letter]

    return mulValue
```

On 300k words, the string hash runs in 0.75s and the prime hash runs in 1s. I've been reading up on this but I'm unable to determine if I've missed anything with this or why it is running slower.

This is already completed as far as the homework is concerned but I want to understand why or what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole bunch of factors going on here:

- `sorted` is O(n log n) average case rather than O(n^2). Worst case of sort is almost never relevant in real programs.
- multiplying primes together is a clever trick, but while it's O(n) cost in multiplications, multiplying a big number N by a small factor is going to be O(log N) in cost rather than O(1) (since you have to go through the O(log N) digits of the bignum). This means the prime technique is going to be O(n log n) too, because keyHash(s) is going to have O(len(s)) digits.
- `n` is small, so implementation details are going to matter a whole lot more than complexity.
- `sorted` is built-in and written in C. The implementation has been tuned over many years. Your prime multiplication code is written in Python.
- You don't say in your question how you performed the timing. It's very easy to get this wrong, by, for example, timing the whole program rather than a micro-benchmark. Given the closeness of the results, I expect you've made such an error, but it's a guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I really do appreciate the feedback.

I had talked it over with friends and we had figured that the multiplication would be a huge factor but weren't sure regarding sorted() and its cost. Was really wanting to just confirm my thinking on this.

Re: feedback on timing, I placed additional timing points in. Timed over the creation and addition of the hashes to the dictionary and then averaged the result to get a "per hash":
string hash - 3.5 microseconds per
prime hash - 4.5 microseconds per